# Recursively searching an array

Tags: java

I need to write a piece of code to test whether the unsorted array **a** contains the value **x**, anywhere from  **start** to **end**, inclusive.

This is what I have so far:

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){
  boolean result = false;
  if(a[start]==x){
    result = true;
  } else {
    linearSearch(a,x,++start,end-1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This current code throws an array out of bounds exception, and I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. Could anyone possibly give me a nudge in the right direction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see anything limiting `start`. Think about what happens when `a[start]` doesn't exist (because it's out of bounds). Either check that it's there or know that it's not (by knowing the length of the array). You're not doing anything with `end` in the method besides subtracting 1 from it each time.

Comment: Also, it is out of bounds by how many? One too far or more? That can tell you whats going on.

Comment: Test your code using pencil and paper. It is not a joke. Try it with a little array following your own algorithm. It can help you a lot. You will discover that you have some out of bounds and that you shrinks the length and advances the front at the same time... and it should do only one.

Comment: Yes, the "end-1" bit, I immediately realized was wrong as soon as I posted the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're having is because you're doing insufficient constraint checking. The constraints you need to ensure are:

- That `start` is less than the length of the array `a`.
- That `end` is less than the length of the array `a`.
- That `end` is greater than `start`.

Even given that, your recursion is problematic because of this line:

```
linearSearch(a,x,++start,end-1);
```

Every time you recurse into this function, the `end` value is decremented. That means the original input for `end` will not actually be the last index checked.

When doing recursion, it is best to think about the *base case*. In this case, what happens if your array is empty? You must return `false:

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){
  if (a.length == 0) { return false; }
  // Do other things
}
```

We also need to determine if we are past the `end` point. This turns out to be the same as the base case:

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){
  if ((a.length == 0) || (end == 0)) { return false; }
  // Do other things
}
```

Now it's a matter of determining if the `head` of the array (the first element) is the `start` position. If not, you skip the check for equality and if so you perform it:

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){
  if ((a.length == 0) || (end == 0)) { return false; }
  if (start <= 0) { //We are within the correct part of the array
     //check for equality
  } // else recurse without checking
}
```

Checking for equality is just `if (head == x)`:

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){
  if ((a.length == 0) || (end == 0)) { return false; }
  if (start <= 0) { //We are within the correct part of the array
     if (a[0] == x) { return true; }
  } 
  //recurse
}
```

Now that we have the *base cases* and *equality case* checked for, we just have to recurse with the proper variables. Here we can decrement `start` and `end` because we are reducing the entire length of the array by one via removal of the `head`. This decrements the index of every element and also the indices of the `start` and `end`. This ensures our base case remains correct.

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){
  if ((a.length == 0) || (end == 0)) { return false; }
  if (start <= 0) { //We are within the correct part of the array
     int head = a[0]; //The head is the first part of an array
     if (head == x) { return true; }
  } 
  // The tail is everything but the head
  int[] tail = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length); //Be careful of off-by-one errors!
  return linearSearch(tail, x, start - 1, end - 1);
}
```

Lets review our constraints:

- That `start` is less than the length of the array `a`.

  - If `start` is greater than the length of the array, `false` is returned because we check to ensure the array has some elements in it first. If we have recursed to the point where the array is empty but there is a higher value in `start`, we will still return.
  - If `start` is zero or less, we will check the equality condition.
- That `end` is less than the length of the array `a`.

  - For the same reason, `end` will always be less than the end of the array or the found variable. (I'm cheating here a little because it's unclear what the expected behavior is.)
- That `end` is greater than `start`.

  - If `end` is less than `start` we return `false` even before `start` has a chance to be checked.

Naturally, it helps to test, so we package it in a class with a `main` and put together some useful tests:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LinearSearch {

    public static boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){
        if ((a.length == 0) || (end == 0)) { return false; }
        if (start <= 0) { //We are within the correct part of the array
            int head = a[0]; //The head is the first part of an array
            if (head == x) { return true; }
        }
        // The tail is everything but the head
        int[] tail = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, (a.length)); //Be careful of off-by-one errors!
        return linearSearch(tail, x, start - 1, end - 1);
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args){
        int[] test_arr1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] test_arr2 = {3,2,3,1,5};
        int[] test_arr3 = {};

        // Basic success test
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 1, 0, 5));
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 2, 0, 5));
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 3, 0, 5));
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 4, 0, 5));
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 5, 0, 5));

        // Test that order doesn't matter
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr2, 1, 0, 5));
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr2, 2, 0, 5));
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr2, 3, 0, 5));
        System.out.println("Expect false Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr2, 4, 0, 5));
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr2, 5, 0, 5));

        // Test that a sub array works correctly
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 3, 2, 4));
        System.out.println("Expect true Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 4, 2, 4));
        System.out.println("Expect false Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 1, 2, 4));
        System.out.println("Expect false Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 2, 2, 4));
        System.out.println("Expect false Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 5, 2, 4));


        // Test empty array
        System.out.println("Expect false Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr3, 3, 1, 2));

        // Test start after finish
        System.out.println("Expect false Found " + LinearSearch.linearSearch(test_arr1, 3, 2, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `tail` need to be declared as an `int` array?

Comment: Ah! Yes. Good catch. Sorry: I didn't actually try to run any of this, and am in more Python-brain right now. Will update.

Comment: Hmm, this actually fails the test cases provided by my instructor. I understand the logic of everything you've done, I just can't figure out where it's going wrong.

Comment: Ah! You have test cases. These are always good things to provide.

Comment: Remember that off-by-one error I warned about? I think I made it in the wrong direction. :) I updated the code for the `copyOfRange()`.

Answer (score 1):

Is the assignment to do it recursively?  Because it would be much easier to just do it with a for loop!

But, in terms of determining what is wrong, thinking about doing it with a for loop can help you figure out what your recursive implementation is missing!

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(), i++) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (a[start] == x) {
        result = true;
    }
}
return result;
```

In the for loop, the middle condition is limiting how many times the loop occurs, which is essentially what you are doing with end.  However, you are not actually verifying that end has changed.

End is the same as the length of the array or just some index you want it to stop searching at.  Recursively, end is acting as a decrementing count.  Once end has decreased to 0, meaning it has checked every element of the array or whatever index you specified to end at.

You need to add an extra conditional to check to see if end == 0 (you've made it through all the elements).

```
boolean result = false;
if (end == 0) {
    return result;
}
else if (a[start] == x) {
    result = true;
    **return result;**
}
else {
     // do recursive search again
}
```

Remember to convert your logic to English when you are forming it: "Okay if we've finished searching each element, return.  No, okay if we found the element, set result to true and return.  Nope, search the next element.

**EDIT: It was pointed out that there was a portion of my answer that was a bit unclear.  The out of bounds exception you were receiving was due to you attempting to access an index larger than the length of the array.  The solution I provided does not check for this as it assumes the user of the function is providing responsible input to the function.

There are two options for handling this case:
1. Add an extra check in the first conditional (if x is greater than the length of the array minus 1 OR end equals 0)
2. In the method declaration add that it throws an Out of Bounds exception so that the user of the function is responsible for validating their input and the output of the function.

There are many different books and materials that discuss these two options and which should or should not be used.  I'll leave that up to you to investigate and decide for yourself.**

Comment: I like your suggestion to talk it out. However, I would note this still fails if `start` is greater than `a.length`.

Comment: @NathanielFord To be fair, the format of his method is implying that the user is passing fair values into the function.  I don't think it's quite accurate to say it falls short -- it just doesn't imply the user is providing phony input.  But hey, I don't want to start the whole "I should make sure the user can't misuse the function" vs "The user should be using the function responsibly" debate.

Comment: I didn't say this 'fell short', but I would note that the OP *explicitly* cited the fact he had an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, which this solution *also* has. Especially with recursive functions you have to be able to honor the contract you provide. I don't think it's a debate: a function should fail gracefully.

Comment: I may have not addressed explicitly that the out of bounds exception was a result of his function attempting to access an element at an index larger than the array.  But, I didn't put the method declaration for the very reason of the exception.  Yes, you can make the function so it will never fail and throw the exception, or you can have the function throw the exception and force the person using it to be responsible for catching that exception and dealing with it.    It's personal preference.

Comment: I recommend the book `Clean Code` on this topic, but I'll avoid arguing that it's not a preference, but a best practice. Like I said, I liked your response (and voted for it).

Comment: @NathanielFord I've read Clean Code -- it's a good book.  Also, preference doesn't imply right, wrong, or best practice.

Answer (score 0):

why not search the effective way?

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x){

    for(int y = 0; y < a.length; y++)
        if(a[y] == x)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

And if you want to search within specified bounds (for example search between element `4` and element `8` instead of whole array), you can use this code:

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){

    for(int y = start; y < end; y++)
        if(a[y] == x)
           return true;

    return false;
}
```

As for your problem,

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){
  boolean result = false;
  if(start == a.length-1)
      return false; // If result still not validated and length limit is reached, return false
  if(a[start] == x){ // When start equals a.length, it throws OFB Exception
    result = true;
  } else{
    linearSearch(a,x,++start,end-1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `for` loops are not inherently 'the effective way'. Both iterative loops and recursion are effective. Further, your recursive solution is incorrect. Specifically, you might recurse many levels and return a value which is never propagated to the top. Consider that you're returning from multiple different points in the function, and your recursive result is never assigned or returned.

Comment: @Nathaniel ah I see. Dayum, that was a silly mistake. I accidentally created something which only checks between specified limits (between `start` and `end`) and not the whole array. Anyway, fixed it. Thanks for letting me know. Also, I wasn't saying that one of loop/recursion is more effective. I meant that it was possible to do this in cleaner way using a few lines only.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? It seems like it would be much simpler.

```
boolean linearSearch(int[] a, int x, int start, int end){
    a = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, start, end);
    return Arrays.asList(a).contains(x);
}
```